# jQuery POST query to my php backend file returns error 502: Bad Gateway if the response is too long

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post, file-get-contents

I'm writting some code to retrieve some json from a website. To avoid CORS, I am triggering the GET from my php file using file_get_contents. The query is successful and the data is sent back. However, when I echo it back to the javascript file, I get a Bad Gateway 502 error. I've noticed that it works fine if I substring a piece of the data I got, and the length cut seems to be around the 1000 characters.

What can be going on here?

Here is the javascript jQuery transaction:

```
function retrieveInfo(authToken) {
    $.post('backend.php',{
        authToken: authToken,
        command: 'RetLst'
    },(data)=> {
        console.log(data);
    },"text");
}
```

Comment: If such an error occurs, there is oftern written some more detailed information to the server's error log. Additionally, you could add some debugging to the PHP script - which you forgot to share

Comment: I didn't think it was relevant. Right now, even if I manually build a long string (over 1000 characters) and echo it back, I get the same error. Same thing happens even if I don't call file_get_contents at all. The php seems to be working just fine. jQuery is just not taking a long string back and I don't know why.

Comment: That has nothing to do with jQuery. jQuery has no influence on the server's response. You should get the same behavior if you use curl, for instance. Check the server's error log and the PHP error log, as suggested by Nico.

Comment: Check if this is PHP error or jQuery, turn on error reporting in PHP `error_reporting(E_ALL)` and an error log file will be generated, if it is a PHP based error

Comment: 502 - an intermeditate server (like a proxy or loadbalancer) has dropped the TCP socket after a timeout while there was no traffic,